# dojo listbox control

Tags: dojo

Is there any list box or similer control in Dojo/dijit/dojox ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [`dijit.form.MultiSelect`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/MultiSelect).

Comment: I dont need a From Control
I just need Plain Divs like <li> with dojo's Tundra CSS

Comment: link is now broken.